# Using "dd" in Vi (delete multi lines) not accepted if number of lines > file length

Tags: vim, vi

I often edit a file locally then cut and paste it into a remote ssh session inside a vi session.

The first step is to delete the entire contents by doing something like

```
 9999dd
```

Which will delete up to 9999 lines of the file.

Now somehow the version of vi on a certain ubuntu machine running 14.04 LTS is behaving differently: it is not allowing the above command if the file does not actually contain at least 9999 rows.

How do I re-enable the former /familiar behavior - in which all lines in the entire file would be erased if N (9999 in this case) exceeds the file line count?

**UPDATE**  I appreciate answers coming in for *alternative* methods to achieve this. However that does not explain why/how/when the behavior changed (I have used Ndd successfully for years. Maybe not the optimal way to do it. But it does work - including on ubuntu - various versions, centos, os/x).

**Another update**  The ":" in front was removed : we are in normal mode. It STILL DOES NOT WORK in this particular editor/vi instance - whereas it works with say 99dd (since the file has > 99 lines)  and also doing the same action 9999dd works in other instances.

Comment: When you have the cursor at the top of the file, type in the key sequence to delete everything in the file:  `dG`  `d` meaning delete, and `G` meaning till end of file.

Comment: Uh, no it doesn't. It doesn't work in any version of Vim.

Comment: @muru Try telling that to my currently open vi sessions.

Comment: @javadba I don't need to.

Comment: @muru " I don't need to". I can not say it any more clearly than I just did it - and did it dozens of times on LTS 14.04 on a different ubuntu machine. So please keep your misinformed OPINION (not fact).

Comment: You don't type with the `:` in the front.  Hit `ESC`, then type in `9999dd`

Comment: @javadba It is not misinformed. I know it for a fact. See my answer.

Comment: @Terrance  Thanks for that info on dG - that does work. re: ESC vs :  doing 99dd works fine (since the file is > 99 lines)

Comment: @javadba Sorry about the extra information, as I used to do tons of support, and old habits die hard.  Everybody has their own way of doing things, and I think your way works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if `vi` has anything like this, but rather than download, edit, upload manually, `emacs` has a feature called TRAMP that lets you open the remote file by url, it automatically downloads the file and opens it, you edit, save, and it automatically uploads it back.  Might be a better fit for your process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@javadba, try `:set nocompatible`

The difference between these two behaviors seems to depend on whether I have `:set nocompatible` in my `~/.vimrc` or in `/etc/vim/vimrc` or wherever the global one is.

If I `:set nocompatible` then I can use `:9999` rather than `:$` to jump to the bottom of a small file, and I can get away with things like `9999dd`.  If I have *not* `:set nocompatible` then nothing happens when I try `9999dd`, and I get an error `E16: Invalid range`  when I try `:9999` to jump to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying (to use an invalid range in command mode), can never have worked. It doesn't work in 7.2.445 (Debian 6), 7.2.411 (CentOS 6.6), 7.3.429 (Ubuntu 12.04), 7.4.683 (Ubuntu 14.04, PPA).

I think you have confused it with `99999dd`, which is valid in normal mode because N here is not a line number, but the number of times the action is repeated - note the absence of `:`.

Indeed, the documentation says as much:

```
Line numbers may be specified with:             :range E14 {address}
        {number}        an absolute line number

....
The {number} must be between 0 and the number of lines in the file.  When
using a 0 (zero) this is interpreted as a 1 by most commands.  Commands that
use it as a count do use it as a zero (:tag, :pop, etc).  Some commands
interpret the zero as "before the first line" (:read, search pattern, etc).
```

---

If you want to delete all lines, and want use the command mode to do so, then:

```
:%d
```

Or, using [ranges](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges):

```
:0,$d
```

If you don't want to use the command mode:

```
ggdG
```

In neither case should you use a weird number for a range.

Comment: This works. It would however still be nice to know : why is my approach - which does work on dozens of other systems - not work on this particular one.

Comment: @javadba Check on all of them, with `vim -u NONE` - disabling your usualy vimrc and plugins.

Comment: @javadba How do I know you even have a shirt on?

Comment: @javadba I'm not saying you didn't do something. I'm *asking* you to do something (check with `vim -u NONE`). It's up to you to do that (or not do that and say "tell that to my vim", which is just as belittling). Notice I haven't downvoted your question for being obviously fantasy.